# Accessing generated data model together with a separate data model in MVC 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a newly built MVC 5 app, using the default template, `PayCaddy.Client`. As built, without any mods, the project creates its own data model, covering entities like `ApplicationUser` for authentication. I like this, just create the project, and it's ready for me to do my own stuff and not worry too much about authentication.

Yet now, my own stuff includes a separate business data model, in a separate project, `PayCaddy.Data`, that includes entities like a bet in a golf game:

```
public class Bet: PayCaddyEntity
{
    public virtual string BetName { get; set; }
    public virtual int Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime OpenedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? ClosedOn { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BetUser> Punters { get; set; }
}
```

Now `ApplicationUser` is used here to indicate the user that initiated the bet, which will be between them and the `Punters`. This leaves me stuck with a circular reference problem, where I need a reference to `PayCaddy.Client` for the `ApplicationUser` entity, and that project needs a reference back for the `Bet` entity.

The Identity framework is highly complex, and simply moving its entities into my data model is out of the question. For now, I have moved my data model into the client project, the same prokect as the Identity code, but I don't want to continue like that if there is a relatively simple way of overcoming this problem. If solutions without days of effort exist, what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try moving the ApplicationUser object out of the MVC project and moving it into your new project. That way all your models are in the one project and your MVC app can just have the one reference to the data project?

*Edit by the OP:*  Just a warning: If you move `ApplicationUser` into your own data model, you must derive your `DbContext` from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`, not plain old `DbContext`, and it's crucial that you call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` in `OnModelCreating`. Normally the base method has no implementation, but here it has some 70 lines of configuration code that is essential to this data model.

Comment: Because the `ApplicationUser` derives from the interminably complex  `IdentityUser`, I put that idea aside, but my data model can just as well also import the .NET libraries to support that. I will try.

Comment: When I've come across this problem in the past I usually just store the username rather than the full ApplicationUser object. You can get this in any controller by accessing User.Identity.Name.

Comment: Yet, it is quite simple and appears to work nicely. Just a little more testing and I'll accept.